# JS Datatables Row Group using objects not working

Tags: datatables

Would Appreciate some assistance reviewing this code and letting me know what I may be doing wrong. I am using ajax with vb.net mvc to load data using json to the view. However, the table is not sorting to show by group.

```
 var table = $("#TblGridInfo").DataTable({
            scrollX: true,
            processing: true, // for show progress bar
            serverSide: true, // for process server side
            filter: true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            orderMulti: true, // for disable multiple column at once
            pageLength: 10,
            responsive: true,

            ajax: {
                url: "/GenerateReport/LoadMCCProductionReport",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
            },


            columns: [
                { data: "MCC", "name": "MCC", "autoWidth": true },
                { data: "Branch", "name": "Branch", "autoWidth": true },
                { data: "MerchantProfileNum", "name": "MerchantProfileNum", "autoWidth": true },
                { data: "BusinessName", "name": "BusinessName", "autoWidth": true },
                { data: "MerchantCode", "name": "MerchantCode", "autoWidth": true },
                { data: "Months", "name": "Months", "autoWidth": true },
                { data: "TotalTrans", "name": "TotalTrans", "autoWidth": true },
                { data: "Volume", "name": "Volume", "autoWidth": true }
            ],

            order: [[0, "asc"]],

            rowGroup: {
                dataSrc: "MCC"
            }


        });
```

Comment: Did you include the RowGroup CSS and JS files in your web page? Downloadable from the Extensions section [here](https://datatables.net/download/), if needed.

Comment: Yes hence my frustration with the issue

Comment: Understood. Sorry, I am not able to recreate your issue with my (simplified) test case. My only observations are: (a) remove any stray punctuation - for example the extra `,` at the end of `datatype: "json",`. I have seen these cause problems several times in the past (but probably not here). And (b) check your browser console for errors (if you have not already done so, of course).

Comment: Alright thanks for the feedback